# Sort searchresults in a Session by a parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list, session

I have a list with searchresults in a Session called Session("ListSearchResults")

In this Sessions there's a bunch of people with all the same info [name, town, age,...]. Now I want to sort Searchresults in the Session by age. Is this possible?

I already tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
Session("ListSearchResults").Sort(Function(x, y) x.age.CompareTo(y.age))
```

Any ideas on how to make this work? (I'm working with vb.net in asp.net)

Comment: It doesn't work means what? The web-server explodes when the age is over 100?

Comment: Since `Session("ListSearchResults")` returns `Object` you need to cast it to `List(Of SearchResult)` if you want to make it compile with Option Strict On(recommended).

Comment: use Session("ListSearchResults").OrderBy(Function(x) x.age).ToList()

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a thing called Casting here. First Convert your Session object to the List of the "Type" you have and then you may use OrderBy to sort the List of Type.